# Issue inserting file into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in html (+ bootstrap), relevant parts here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPic">Item Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="inputPic">
    <p class="help-block">Upload a picture</p>
</div>
```

User presses submit and is brought to another php file which checks the files extension:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name']))
{
    if ($_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/png")
    {
        if ($content = file_get_contents($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name']))
        {
            $image = addslashes($content);
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly attempts to insert into sql:

```
if (isset($image))
{
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posted_items (seller, post_date, expiration, image, description, name, category, startBid, buyNowPrice, minPrice, sold) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("issssiddd", $userid, $endDateAndTime, $image, $description, $itemName, $itemCategory, $startBid, $buyNow, $reservation);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

The sql insert is working properly as I see it in my database but the image (type largeblob) is not showing up at all for me. There is a bunch of random data in the database in the image field but when I call

```
echo '< img class="img-responsive centered" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"></img>';
```

I am unable to see anything. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: ANY ERROR/EXCEPTION MESSAGE?

Comment: can you add what Error you are getting

Comment: No errors, just cannot display the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather upload the image to some directory on your server and save the path in your database.